# Program to swap files between drives?

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer

Has anyone built a program/script to transfer files between 2 hard drives, but like if both are near full....so one copies 1 file over then the other copies the other file, then they delete the files that were copied?

Kind of annoying, have a 6tb raid at about 4tb full, then 1 4.5tb basically full, can't really swap them easily....without doing many copies and deletes of files....

Anyone know a way to make them just swap? lol

Comment: I guess you will not find such a program. Think what happens if the operation is interrupted, your files will become totally broken. Try archiving these files or use a temporary storage, e.g. a flash drive.

Comment: Would love to find a flash drive that's 4.5tb -.- >_< I don't have enough spare storage to do this quickly that's the main problem

Comment: Ah *Tera*. Sorry for a misleading idea. Well, it looks you have 6-4=2Tb free space on the 1st RAID and 4.5Tb data on each. It's only 3 iterations, not *that* annoying. :)

Comment: Not terrible, just annoying as can't leave it to go on while I sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is writing a small script (batch file) would be sufficient.

Assuming you have 1.5Tb on one of the drives, identify three blocks of 1.5Tb on each drive and write a batch file that will do the job.

You may also semi-automate this process. Assuming you are on Windows, want to copy drives `X:` and `Y:`, and each file is smaller than your free space (1.5Tb).
**Robocopy** which is a part of [Windows 2003 resource kit tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)

```
: repeat
robocopy X:\ Y:\From_X /MOVE /XD From_Y
if errorlevel 2 GOTO cont

SET FIRST_OK=1

: cont
robocopy Y:\ X:\From_Y /MOVE /XD From_X
if errorlevel 2 GOTO repeat

IF "%FIRST_OK"="1" GOTO end
GOTO repeat

: end
move X:\From_Y X:\
move Y:\From_X Y:\
```

See [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) for `errorlevel`'s returned by `robocopy`. `2` or higher means yet not done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a shell script (powershell, bash).

```
L1 := files to move on disk a
L2 := files to move on disk b

while (L1 has files or L2 has files) and (l1 or l2 is true) 
   l1 := file from L1 that fits on b
   l2 := file from L2 that fits on a
   if l1
      move l1 to b
   if l2
      move l2 to a
```