# How can I transfer all content of two drives between each other automatically?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, file-transfer

I have two, nearly full, external hard drives of equal size.

I want to transfer all content from one drive to the other, and vice-versa.

Is there a way to do this automatically, without having to manually and successively transfer files between the two drives until all of the content has been switched?

I.e., is there a program, or command, that I can leave running by itself until drive 1 contains all of drive 2's content, and drive 2 contains all of drive 1's content?

I have access to both Windows and Linux, but not to an intermediary to temporarily store the data of one drive.

Comment: Ask any of your friends or acquaintances to borrow their external USB drive, then either do an XCOPY or partition copy. This is much easier, faster and less error prone than any 'move some files to A, move some files to B, move more files to A,...' scenario - even an automatic one.

Comment: I was afraid it was the only option, and since no one has a single drive with enough free space, I was looking for alternatives. What errors are you mentioning, assuming hash checks will be done during the transfers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a [duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/508613/program-to-swap-files-between-drives), this [little script by bytebuster](https://superuser.com/questions/508613/program-to-swap-files-between-drives/508704#508704) may be of help. It simply moves files back and forth between drives X: and Y: into Y:\fromX and X:\fromY until it runs out of free space on current destination drive, then switches source/dest over until there are no dirs except Y:\fromX and X:\fromY.

Of course, it will only work if none of the drives contain files bigger than the sum of free spaces on both drives, and it may not work even then (due to file order and it being a really simple script). To work safely, it needs each drive to have free space bigger than the largest file being transferred.

It's really simple and if you prefer Linux, you could easily rewrite it using bash / rsync with `rsync --remove-source-files --exclude=dir` instead of `robocopy /MOVE /XD dir`.

Comment: When I try to flag it as a duplicate, I receive a 404 error message. It looks just like what is described in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187255/404-error-during-flagging-a-question) at SO.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to do this kind of synchronization.  It is built on top of the `rsync` protocol.  Among other uses, I keep my documents directories in sync between Windows and Linux.  Change conflicts need to be handled manually, but deletes are handled intelligently.

The first run will take a while, after that only changes need to be handled.

EDIT:  I misread your original requirement.  To my mind this is a strange requirement, unless for some reason you have the files you want portable on a larger drive, and files you don't want portable on another drive.  Not having intermediate space is also strange.

If the files on either disk are compressible, then creating a compressed archive (zip, tar, etc.) of one drive to your system, moving files between drives, and then restoring the original archive to the other drive would work.  Alternatively, compress the file on both disks with gzip. Move files back and forth, and uncompress.

If you want move files to A, move files to B, move files to A... then `rsync` with find rules alone may do what you need.  A little shell script around it to switch directions on each pass would be required.  The directories on both systems would need to be different.  You may have to rearrange/rename directories for the move.

Comment: I may have been ambiguous in my opening question, but I am looking for a tool that does what Jan Doggen described: 'move some files to A, move some files to B, move more files to A,...'. Does Unison support that? From what I could understand, it's a synchronization tool which is used to make two folders/drives hold the same information.

Comment: @JohnSmith Misread your original requirement which seems unreasonably restrictive and likely to fail due to having a file larger than freespace.  I've offered a couple of options.